# multiply two decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add a tax field. I have this working for whole numbers but i need to be able to enter ".5"
I have no clue haw to solve this problem maybe its because of the isNAN but i thought this would be ok here.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/eeMva/3/

My current code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    calculateSum();
    $(".txt").keyup(function() {
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

$("#tax").keyup(function() {
    $('#total1').val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#subtotal').val()));
);

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value == "";
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value = sum;


    function getTax(tax) {
        var taxFloat = parseFloat(tax)
        if (isNaN(taxFloat)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return taxFloat;
        }
    }

    var total = getTax($('#tax').val()) * sum;
    var total1 = document.getElementById("total1").value = total;
} ​
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you encounter `NaN`? `!isNaN(".5")` gives `true` for me.

Comment: Proper indentation increases the readability of your code and makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Your code is somewhat messy. The `keyup` function you added to the field '#tax' is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean @madth3

Comment: Did u try to enter a decimal for the tax value @Bergi

Comment: I formatted it better on the fiddle sorry I'm on my phone! @Felix

Comment: @tman: If you enter the tax first and then some values, it works. See my answer for the Why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Put all code including functions inside your `$(document).ready(function(){...})` structure.
- Perform all calculations, including tax, inside `calculateSum()`.
- Use jQuery all through, in particular '$(...)' in preference to `.getelementById(...)`.
- Attach `calculateSum` as the 'keyup' handler for all the user-enterable fields.
- Purge all sorts of junk from the code

It should look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getTax() {
        var taxFloat = parseFloat($("#tax").val());
        return isNaN(taxFloat) ? 1 : taxFloat;
    }

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            if (this.value && !isNaN(this.value)) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#subtotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
            $("#total1").val((getTax()*sum).toFixed(2));
    }

    $(".txt, #tax").keyup(calculateSum);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eeMva/19/)**

You probably want to change the tax algorithm to something more logical. eg. for an entered value of 5(%), the multiplier should be 1.05 .

Comment: "*Purge all sorts of junk from the code*". Yes, that's obviously the way to go :-)

Comment: I do so frequently @Bergi, sometimes from other people's code and very often from my own!

Answer (score 0):

Taxes are based on percentages. Do the following changes:

```
$("#tax").keyup(function() { 
    //$('#total1').val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#subtotal').val()));
    calculateSum();
    });

...

function getTax(tax) {
        var taxFloat = parseFloat(tax)
        if (isNaN(taxFloat)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            // 1(subtotal) + ?(tax%) -> total = (1 + tax%) * subtotal
            return 1 + (taxFloat/100);
        }
    }

    var total = getTax($('#tax').val()) * sum;
    // round to 2 decimal digits
    total = Math.round(total * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
    var total1 = document.getElementById("total1").value = total;
```

So for 5% you enter 5 for 0.5% you enter .5

**UPDATE**: (Not really an update) As I see more answers coming in, I repeat the logical error for tax field usage. Taxes are percentages worldwide, Meaning that the problem was not only the keyup handling, but also the way tax value was used.

Comment: Thanks so much I will try it in about 30 min

Comment: I modified your jsfiddle code like above before answering and there is no problem. Please describe the problem(s).

Comment: @tman, No you did not try what @drdigit did. Notice how he changed the `$("#tax").keyup` part.

Comment: Typing in .5 in the tax text box

Comment: Ok yes I missed that I saw the ... And thought it was just after this where changes were

Answer (score 0):

Found your error:

```
$("#tax").keyup(function() {
     $('#total1').val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#subtotal').val()));
});
```

Here, you parse the tax with `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`, as you do in the function `getTax`. `parseInt(".5")` gives NaN. Try to insert values in the `.txt` inputs after having inserted a tax, and it would work when invoking the `calculateSum` function.

I can't understand why you would use a different computation when pressing keys in the `#tax` field than on normal keypresses in other fields. Just use the same listener function, or, if you want to divide the functionality, invoke the function to display the tax both from the `#tax` keyhandler and the `calculateSum` function.

Also, there is no need to execute `calculateSum()` four times when one of the inputs is updated.

See better structured source code in [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeMva/18/). The maths to calculate taxes and totals was not corrected.

Comment: I'd love to see what you would consider a well written code to execute this function! Im building on what I know! But your points do seem valid I'm not sure how you would build it to only execute 1 time